# Continuity of a non linear map $U:C^0([0,1])\rightarrow C^0([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Consider the non linear map $U:C^0([0,1])\rightarrow C^0([0,1])$ defined by $$U(f)(x)=e^{-f(x)^2}$$
Show that $U$ is continuous.

I know various definition of continuity, like the definition in terms of limits of functions $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=f(c)$$
the definition in terms of limits of sequences $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=c \implies \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=f(c)$$
or moreover the geometric definition $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if for every open set $V\subset Y$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.

Now, probably the solution is very easy but I can't understand what I have to use and where I have to start, with some formula or property.

Someone could help me?

Comment: Two things. First: which topology are you assuming in $C^0\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$? Second: why do you mention a theorem about linear functionals when your function is neither linear nor a functional?

Comment: Yeah you're right my fault, i haven't got any infos on the topology on $C^0([0,1])$

Comment: Assuming $C^0$ is endowed with a metric topology, then show that $f_n \to f$ implies that $Uf_n \to Uf$ in $C^0$, for any sequence $f_n \in C^0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard metric on $C([0,1])$ is $d(f,g) = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)|$.

Consider the function $h(x) = e^{-x^2}$.  For any two points $x,y \in \mathbb R$ you could use (for instance) the mean value theorem to find
$$h(x) - h(y) = h'(z) (x-y)$$
for some point $z$ in between $x$ and $y$.  Since $h'(z) = e^{-z^2}(-2z)$, it is not hard to show using the first derivative test that $h'$ is bounded above and below by $1$ and $-1$ respectively. Thus $|h'(z)| \le 1$ for all $z$ and $$|h(x) - h(y)| \le |x-y|.$$

For any point $x \in [0,1]$ you get
$$|Uf(x) - Ug(x)| = |h(f(x)) - h(g(x))| \le |f(x) - g(x)| \le d(f,g).$$
This leads to
$$ d(Uf,Ug) = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |Uf(x) - Ug(x)| \le d(f,g).$$
From here the continuity of $U$ is easily established using an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.

Comment: So nice, i need to convince me of some things you used here, but it seems to be a beautiful solution. Thanks

Comment: @UmbertoP. very smart solution. In the last line, instead of using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ argument, can we just say that $U$ is Lipschitz continuous and so also continuous?

Comment: You bet.$\mbox{}$

Comment: @UmbertoP. "you bet" $\equiv$ "sì, certo" ?

Comment: @soundwave yes, indeed.

Comment: @UmbertoP. grazie!

Comment: @UmbertoP. excuse me, I have a one more question. In the case the norms of the two spaces (domain and codomain) are different, would this argument hold?

Comment: @UmbertoP. for example the identity map $\text{Id}:  (C^0[a, b], ||·||_1) → (C^0[a, b], ||·||_∞)$

Comment: The comment section isn't the place to ask new questions - you should post this as a question.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Ciao Umberto, what if the derivative $h'$ is not defined for a point in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. $h$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: I was doing the same exercise with $U$ defined by $U(f)(x)=\log(1+|f(x)|)$, so $h(x)=\log(1+|x|)$ and $h'(x)=\frac{x}{|x|+x^2}$ which is not defined in $0$.

Comment: Your $h$ is even: if $x,y > 0$ then $|h(x) - h(y)| \le |x-y|$. if $x < 0$ and $y > 0$ then $$|h(x) - h(y)| = |h(|x|) - h(y)| \le | |x| - y| \le |x-y|$$ et cetera.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Is it not important the fact that $h'(0)$ is not defined?